# Difficulty understanding the definition of the Barycentric coordinate system

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

Specifically, the definition at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_%28mathematics%29#Definition

> Let $x_1, \dots , x_n$ be the vertices of a simplex in a vector space $A$. If, for some point in $A$,
>   $$(a_1 + \dots + a_n)P = (a_1)(x_1) + \dots + (a_n)(x_n)$$
>   and at least one of $a_1, \dots , a_n$ does not vanish then we say that the coefficients...

Before I finish the definition, I need help in understanding what that first bit means.  For example, what does it mean for vertices to be added together and multiplied by another vertex?  Or multiplied together?  What does it mean to say a point does not vanish?

Comment: These are vectors. Try drawing pictures with two or three vectors in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: The $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are real numbers, not points.

Comment: The $a_i$ are real numbers and the $x_i$ are vectors. For a warm-up, consider all points (vectors) of the form $ax + (1-a)y$, starting with vectors $x$ and $y$ in the plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm trying to follow you, but we need to take a step back.  Why am I adding the x and y values after multiplying them?  And how does that result in a vector?  Edit: Oh.  x and y are vectors.  Use a and b next time!  If I see "x", "y", and "plane" i'm assuming (x, y)

Comment: @TedShifrin It looks like the new vector generated lies on a line segment directly between x and y, closer to the vector multiplied by the higher of the values a and (1 - a).

Comment: This is right when $0\le a\le 1$. However, in general, $a$ can take on any real value and you get all the points on the line joining $x$ and $y$.